# Evaluating noise variance to achieve desired accuracy in MMSE estimation problem

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

I unable to solve item 2 from the problem posted below, solution or tips are appreciated.

### My attempt

I read item 2 as
$$
P\{|\frac{\hat{x} - x}{x}| < 0.1\} = 0.99 \tag{1}\label{base}
$$
where $\hat{x} = \bar{x} - P_{xz}P_{zz}^{-1}(z-\bar{z})$ is MMSE estimator. 
$z = \begin{bmatrix}z_1 \\ z_2\end{bmatrix}$ is random vector of measurements, $P_{xz}$ is cross-covariance of $x$ and $z$, $P_{zz}$ is covariance of $z$, and $\bar{z}$ is expectation of $z$.

$$
P_{xz} = \sigma_{0}^2 \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\end{bmatrix} 
$$

$$
P_{zz} = E[(z - \bar{z})(z - \bar{z})'] = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
     \sigma_{0}^2 + \sigma^2  & \sigma_{0}^2 + \rho \sigma^2 \\
     \sigma_{0}^2 + \rho \sigma^2 & \sigma_{0}^2 + \sigma^2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\bar{z} = \bar{x}
$$

Evaluating $\sigma$ from $\eqref{base}$ is doubtful. For one thing $\frac{\hat{x} - x}{x}$ is not Gaussian. I though that it might be acceptable replace $x$ by $\bar{x}$ in denominator and calculate
$$
P_{\hat{x}|z}\{|\frac{\hat{x} - x}{\bar{x}}| < 0.1\} = 0.99
$$

$$
P_{\hat{x}|z}\{|\frac{\hat{x} - x}{\sqrt{P_{xx|z}}}| < \frac{0.1\bar{x}}{\sqrt{P_{xx|z}}}\} = 0.99 \tag{2}\label{aprx}
$$
With assumption that $x$ is expected value of $\hat{x}$ conditioned on measurements.

$\eqref{aprx}$ is standardization of $\hat{x}$. Using Normal distribution probabilities table

$$
\frac{0.1\bar{x}}{\sqrt{P_{xx|z}}} = 2.58 \Leftrightarrow \Big(\frac{0.1\bar{x}}{2.58}\Big)^{2} = P_{xx|z} = \frac{(1+\rho) \sigma_{0}^{2} \sigma^{2}}{2\sigma_{0}^{2}  + (1+\rho) \sigma^{2}}   
\tag{3}\label{final}
$$

From $\eqref{final}$ I can calculate $\sigma=0.48$. To check my solution I simulated estimation for 10000 times and get $1\%$ accuracy. My solution is too low. By simulating with different values $\sigma=0.9$ is correct value.

Either my simulation has errors or my solutions has errors.

### Problem description

Given the prior information $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\bar{x}, \sigma_{0}^2)$
and the measurements
$$
z(j) = x + w(j) \quad j=1,2\
$$
with the jointly Gaussian measurements noises $w(j) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_{0}^2)$ independent of $x$ but correlated among themselves, with
$$ 
E[w(1)w(2)] = \rho \sigma^2 
$$

1. Find the variance of the MMSE estimator of $x$ conditioned on these measurements.
2. If $\bar{x}=10$, $\sigma_0=1$ and $\rho=0.5$, how accurate should the measurements be (i.e., find $\sigma$)
   if we want the estimate to be within $10\%$ of the true value with $99\%$ probability.

Source:
Estimation with Applications to Tracking and Navigation: Theory Algorithms and Software
Yaakov Bar-Shalom, X. Rong Li, Thiagalingam Kirubarajan

Comment: I think my solution might be correct. I was interpreting my simulation incorrectly. With $\sigma=0.48$ I get that approx. $1.3\%$ of all simulation runs have error larger then $10\%$. But it is unclear to me why I can replace $x$ by $\bar{x}$ in the denominator of (2)